# How to determine if $var is a present in array as complete word

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I have the following problem:
I have a array `array=(test3 testtest)`.
Now I have a variable `var` and I want to test if var is not present in the array, but match only complete words:
Example:

```
test3 would match
test not
```

I have the following code already, which is working for finding occurencies, but not for complete words only, `test` is found as a match:
`if ! [[ ${array[*]} =~ test ]];  then echo "Not in"; fi`
I have a second try to achcieve this, but with this code `test3` is not found as well:
`if ! [[ ${array[*]} =~ \<test\> ]];  then echo "Not in"; fi`
I want to achieve this, without any loop if that is possbile.
So my question is:
Is it possbile to do that without any loop?
If it is not, how can I do this with a loop?
My problem is, that this if statement is already in an exisiting loop, setting values for `var`. So if I have a loop in a loop, which I think, is not very good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not entirely understand what you're asking, but does the following code help you? It searches items in `array0` and matches it against whole words in `array1`

```
#!/bin/bash
array0=(test3 testtest)
array1=(testtest bla test3)

for i in "${array1[@]}"; do
        echo -ne "$i: \t"
        if ! [[ ${array0[*]} =~ ([[:space:]]|^)$i([[:space:]]|$) ]]; then
                echo "Not in"; 
        else
                echo "Yes in";
        fi
done
exit 0
```

To match against whole words, you have to wrap the string with `([[:space:]]|^)` and `([[:space:]]|$)`. This allows the word to be wrapped with spaces, or to exist at the beginning (`^`) or at the end (`$`) of the line.

Comment: the spaces did it, thanks. i use now:
`if ! [[ " ${array[@]} " =~ " test " ]]; then`

Answer (score 0):

It seemed to work with the code you provided in the previous post.

Here was my output:

> test3 testtest
>
> In Array

Here's the exact code that I used:

```
array=(test3 testtest)
echo ${array[*]}

if ! [[ ${array[*]} =~ test ]];
then echo "Not in Array";
else echo 'In Array';
fi
```

Comment: The solution you provided checks whether the string 'test' is present in the array. @TNT2k asks for an exact match of words. Where 'test3' would match but 'test' doesn't match. Do you have an alternative solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try an *associative* array for the lookup.

```
$: declare -A lookup=()
$: list=( test3 would match )
$: for item in "${list[@]}"; do lookup[$item]=1; done

$: [[ -n "${lookup[test]}" ]] && echo found || echo nope 
nope

$: [[ -n "${lookup[test3]}" ]] && echo found || echo nope 
found
```

This doesn't have much value if the array isn't fairly stable, though, because you'd have to keep rebuilding it. In that case, you might as well just use a brute-force loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not pretty, but I believe this will work as a condition:

```sh
printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}" | grep -q -e '^test$'
```

... assuming the array members can't have newlines.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a loop.

```
# Exit status 0 if the argument is not one of the array elements.
# Exit status 1 as soon as a match is found.
match () {
  for x in "${array[@]}"; do
    [[ $1 = "$x" ]] && return 1
  done
  return 0
}
```

The whole point of an array is to provide a container that can distinguish two elements without the use of any kind of delimiter. Flattening the array with `[*]` does away with that guarantee.

Comment: the goal ist to not use a loop, see my explanation below the code block

Comment: Well, I have now a solution without a loop, and it is working great. The var will not contain spaces or special chars and such stuff, because it is only the name of a docker image :)